# Can we pass a route var to an ajax $http.get

Tags: angularjs

This is what i want:

```
$http.get('v1/service/:variable', { params: { variable: 'val' } })
```

so i know that this still just adds the `val` as a query param, but i want it to replace the `:variable`.
Do you see this happening?

Comment: please update the example, `var` is a keyword in javascript, which can be confusing.

Comment: Please, explain in more detail: what you want, or provide JSfiddle/Plunker.

Comment: @ArtyomPranovich its simple: i want to be able to map the params hash to the route params. The resulting url from the above example should be: 'v1/service/val'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS's `$http` does not support this.

You'll have to do the replacing yourself.

```
var url = 'v1/service/:variable';
var params = {
    variable: 'val' 
};

for(var varName in params) {
    url = url.replace(':' + varName, params[varName]);
}

$http.get(url);
```

Or go with a `sprintf`-like [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format).

Comment: I was hoping angular had it implemented somehow.. But even with your approach, if variable has something like '+val', it's not gonna be encoded to '%2Bval'. Or it doesn't need to be? Thought?

Comment: Well, why not do a `encodeURIComponent(params[varName])`?

Comment: Makes sense. Now, don't forget to do a pull request to angularjs.